# LaTeX: How to create appendix ToC

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I want a ToC in the beginning of my appendix, which only lists the elements in the appendix.

```
\begin{appendix}
    \chapter{Appendix}
    % Appendix ToC here
    \newpage
    \section{Appendix 1}
    ...
    \section{Appendix 2}
    ...
\end{appendix}
```

Is there any one who knows how I can do this?

Comment: Which documentclass are you using? ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}